# How to create a calendar in postgresql with python for web application?

Tags: python, postgresql, calendar, backend, fastapi

I need to make the backend of a web application with python that should serve as an "activity calendar" of an organization.  In general, it is simply a calendar where each employee's activities can be scheduled so that senior managers can see in real time what each one is doing.  My idea is to create this calendar in a postgresql database so that queries can be made there.  I have some doubts about how I should implement it, should I design the calendar myself to create it in the database or is there a python tool that already helps me with this?

Comment: I have done something similar using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/) as the framework, [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) as the calender, utilizing the [RRule plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin). In Python I use the `dateutil` module [rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) to save events to Postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't store the calendar days per say, but instead store each event as a row in the table with the user, date and time. Then you can return each event in your backend, where you can populate your calendar UI.

For the model itself, I would use something like [SQL Alchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/quickstart.html) (or [Django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/) if you're working with Django).

E.g, define your event model.

```
class CalendarEvent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'calendar_events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    ...
```

Then you could fetch all events for a user and use in your view to hydrate a calendar UI.

```
calendar_events = CalendarEvents.query.filter(user_id=123)
```

Note that there are some considerations to take into account like recurring events and handling timezones for users.